# Select next or previous image

Tags: php

- Code Selects images from a directory and displays them in a table.does what I want, but, cant get the PREVIOUS or NEXT buttons to show next image. I have looked at many site and Stack but no luck,  any help much appreciated

  ```
          <?php function RandomImage()
          {
              $randnum = 0;
              print("<UL>\n");
              $myDir = dir("./images");
              $icount = 1;
              while($entryName = $myDir->read())
              {       
                  $icount++;
              }

              $myDir->close();
              $myDir = dir("./images");
              rewinddir();
              srand(time());
              $randnum = rand(3,($icount-2)+1);

              for($i=0;$i<$randnum;$i++)
              {   
                  $entryName = $myDir->read();
                  $myimage = $entryName;
              }

              return('images/' . $myimage);
          }
          ?>

          <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
          <title>Club Photo's</title>
          </head>

          <body>
          <?php
              $picture = RandomImage();
              echo $picture;
          ?>
          <table width="250" height="237" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
              <tr>
                  <br><td><div align="center">Club Photo's </div></td><br>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><img name="myImage" src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" width="460" height="315" alt=""></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
          <br><input name="Previous" type="button" value="previous" />
          <input name="Next" type="button" value="next" onClick=img name="myImage" src="<?php echo $picture; ?>"/> 

          </body>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Simple put two html button and if suppose you are showing six image at a time, then when user click on next button then simply hide first image and show seventh image and hide it through css and so on...same goes for previous button. Remember that when the last six images are shown, then the next button should not hide the first element inn the section..

Comment: Thank you for your input, however being very new at php the word simple does not apply to me. Nothing is simple when you are learning. But, thanks for your insight I will try and work it out